# Restrict a routine to use a limited set of registers

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, arm, cpu-registers

Using compiler option, is it possible to restrict a routine from using certain set of registers?

For example: Restrict a routine to use only R0-R8;

Purpose: If some compiler option available, then I could ensure certain routines (like Interrupt Service Routines) to use only limited register set, and thus do limited Context Save & Restore.

Comment: Here is a similar question on [registers and threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718484/is-it-possible-to-share-a-register-between-threads).  As it relates to the ARM, the IRQ already has banked `sp` and `lr`.  The [FIQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973933/what-is-the-difference-between-fiq-and-irq-interrupt-system) has even more banked registers and it is probably your solution.  The use of `-ffixed-reg` can also be used.  As per the first link, when you reserve **general purpose**  registers like this you handicap the compiler and force it to use memory in most functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[When this was last discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126597/limit-use-of-registers-in-c), the consensus was that it is not possible on a function-by-function basis.

There are ways to restrict register use throughout an entire compilation, so if you put your interrupt routines in a separate compilation unit, you can use [the `gcc` switch `-ffixed-reg`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-ffixed-2684). I believe it would be used like `-ffixed-R0` if you wanted the compiler to not generate code using `R0`.