# When to use earlyclobber constraint in extended GCC inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I understand when to use a clobber list (e.g. listing a register which is modified in the assembly so that it doesn't get chosen for use as an input register, etc), but I can't wrap my head around the the earlyclobber constraint `&`. If you list your outputs, wouldn't that already mean that inputs can't use the selected register (aside from matching digit constraints)?

For example:

```
asm(
    "movl $1, %0;"
    "addl $3, %0;"
    "addl $4, %1;"   // separate bug: modifies input-only operand
    "addl %1, %0;"
    : "=g"(num_out)
    : "g"(num_in)
    :
);
```

Would `&` even be needed for the output variables? The compiler should know the register that was selected for the output, and thus know not to use it for the input.

Comment: Related: [Concrete example of incorrect behavior of an early-clobber affecting a memory operand's addressing mode in GCC inline asm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67645020)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By default, the compiler assumes all inputs will be consumed before any output registers are written to, so that it's allowed to use the same registers for both. This leads to better code when possible, but if the assumption is wrong, things will fail catastrophically. The "early clobber" marker is a way to tell the compiler that this output will be written before all the input has been consumed, so it cannot share a register with any input.

GNU C inline asm syntax was designed to wrap a *single* instruction as efficiently as possible.  You can put multiple instructions in an asm template, but the defaults (assuming that all inputs are read before any outputs are written) are designed around wrapping a single instruction.

It's the same constraint syntax as GCC uses in its machine-description files that teach the compiler what instructions are available in an ISA.

Comment: So that means that the compiler could assume, for example, that the `eax` register I use for an input is no longer needed by the time the output is needed, so it reuses the `eax` register? Does this mean the output in my code in the original question does in fact require a `&` modifier?

Comment: Your code is wrong for multiple reasons. For instance, you're modifying an input register.

Comment: A typical "earlyclobber" for x86 is the use of extending multiplication, where `EDX:EAX` / `RDX:RAX` _implicitly_ are outputs. When those instructions are used in a multi-input `asm()` statement, the `d` and `a` registers can not be used as input after the earlyclobber output "consumed" the contents. If that specific input operand is used more than once, the compiler will put it into a _different_ register.

Comment: Related about *why* we need to tell the compiler about stuff, and the design philosophy: [Why we need Clobbered registers list in Inline Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69453851)  (I already added a couple paragraphs in this answer about why it's designed this way.)

Comment: Interesting note about the original design intent being a single instruction. Ive been reading some GCC documentation on inline ASM and it kept using the singular word 'instruction' to refer to the contents of the ASM. It did this often enough that I figured it couldn't have been a typo.

Answer (score 16):

**Minimal educational example**

Here I provide a minimal educational example that attempts to make what https://stackoverflow.com/a/15819941/895245 mentioned clearer.

This specific code is of course not useful in practice, and could be achieved more efficiently a single `lea 1(%q[in]), %out` instruction, it is just a simple educational example.

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    uint64_t in = 1;
    uint64_t out;
    __asm__ (
        "mov %[in], %[out];" /* out = in */
        "inc %[out];"        /* out++ */
        "mov %[in], %[out];" /* out = in */
        "inc %[out];"        /* out++ */
        : [out] "=&r" (out)
        : [in] "r" (in)
        :
    );
    assert(out == 2);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -std=c99 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
./main.out
```

This program is correct and the assert passes, because `&` forces the compiler to choose different registers for `in` and `out`.

This is because `&` tells the compiler that `in` might be used after `out` was written to, which is actually the case here.

Therefore, the only way to not wrongly modify `in` is to put `in` and `out` in different registers.

The disassembly:

```
gdb -nh -batch -ex 'disassemble/rs main' main.out
```

contains:

```
   0x0000000000001055 <+5>:     48 89 d0        mov    %rdx,%rax
   0x0000000000001058 <+8>:     48 ff c0        inc    %rax
   0x000000000000105b <+11>:    48 89 d0        mov    %rdx,%rax
   0x000000000000105e <+14>:    48 ff c0        inc    %rax
```

which shows that GCC chose `rax` for `out` and `rdx` for `in`.

If we remove the `&` however, the behavior is unspecified.

In my test system, the assert actually fails, because the compiler tries to minimize register usage, and compiles to:

```
   0x0000000000001055 <+5>:     48 89 c0        mov    %rax,%rax
   0x0000000000001058 <+8>:     48 ff c0        inc    %rax
   0x000000000000105b <+11>:    48 89 c0        mov    %rax,%rax
   0x000000000000105e <+14>:    48 ff c0        inc    %rax
```

therefore using `rax` for both `in` and `out`.

The result of this is that `out` is incremented twice, and equals `3` instead of `2` in the end.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10 amd64, GCC 8.2.0.

**More practical examples**

- [multiplication implicit output registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819794/when-to-use-earlyclobber-constraint-in-extended-gcc-inline-assembly#comment22989396_15819941)
- non-hardcoded scratch registers: [GCC: Prohibit use of some registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682733/gcc-prohibit-use-of-some-registers/54963829#54963829)

Comment: Worth mentioning that this example is only an intentionally simplistic easy-to-understand example.  An `asm` statement where the first or last instruction is `mov` usually means you're doing it wrong.  Use constraints to get the compiler to put inputs where you want them, or take outputs wherever you leave them (even in EFLAGS with GCC6 condition-code outputs.)  Also, x86 can copy-and-increment with `lea 1(%q[in]), %out`.  (`q` modifier to force 64-bit address size, regardless of output size. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers)

Comment: @PeterCordes definitely, that code is useless. A useful example would also be a good addition.

Comment: Nothing jumped to mind immediately, just thought it would be worth a comment in the code for the benefit of people trying to learn inline asm in general that it should basically never start with `mov`, because constraints.  (Although copying a input that you read multiple times is one actually reasonable use-case.)

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 Another use of `=&r`, which nobody seems to have mentioned explicitly, is having temporary register variables that one can refer to by meaningful names, e.g. `%[running_sum]` instead of hard-coded `%r8`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze cool! I ended up adding an example of that at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682733/gcc-prohibit-use-of-some-registers/54963829#54963829

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Yup, and even better that lets the compiler pick a convenient register for you, instead of hard-coding register allocation choices in the asm template.