# Double assignment using inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, avr, inline-assembly, avr-gcc

Following [this manual](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html) I wanted to create simplest inline AVR assembly snippet possible: copy values of two variables to two other variables.

```
uint8_t a, b, c, d;
a = 42;
b = 11;
asm(
    "mov %0, %2\n\t"
    "mov %1, %3\n\t"
    : "=r" (c), "=r" (d)
    : "r" (a), "r" (b)
);
```

I would expect it to be equivalent to:

```
uint8_t a, b, c, d;
a = 42;
b = 11;
c = a;
d = b;
```

However, after running both values of `c` and `d` are equal to *42*. If I change the asm snipptet to:

```
asm(
    "mov %0, %3\n\t"
    "mov %1, %2\n\t"
    : "=r" (c), "=r" (d)
    : "r" (a), "r" (b)
);
```

`c` is equal to *11* and `d` is equal to *42* as expected. Similarly, changing both source operands to `%2` yields two *42* and setting both of them to `%3` yields two *11*.

Why the first version does not work as intended?

Comment: This question would be better with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the exact command line used to compile the code.

Comment: Presumably the compiler allocated an input overlapping with an output. You should mark the outputs as early-clobber (ie. `"=&r"`). Also, you should examine the generated assembly code when in doubt (use `gcc -S`). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567746/unexpected-gcc-inline-asm-behaviour-clobbered-variable-overwritten).

Comment: It looks like Jester has correctly identified the most likely cause of your problem (especially by encouraging you to get used to using -S).  But let me offer an educational alternative: `asm("" : "=r" (c), "=r" (d) : "0" (a), "1" (b));`.  The way this works is that "0" means that this parameter goes in the same place as parameter #0 (likewise for "1").  So, on input, the first register will contain (a), and on output it will contain (c).  Since that's already exactly what you want, no additional asm is required.  Cool, eh?

Comment: @user3386109 Well, I was actually using Arduino IDE to compile the code so it would be quite bloated and hard to reproduce anyway for someone who does not have Arduino libraries. I guess I have to get friendly with AVR command line tools, especially after @Jester advice. And yes, lack of `=&r` was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect it to be equivalent to:
> `uint8_t a, b, c, d;`
> `a = 42;`
> `b = 11;`
> `c = a;`
> `d = b;`

No, it's not<sup>1</sup>. The reason is that in the C code, one assignment follows after the other, whereas in inline asm, the compiler treats the "code" as if it happens **at once**.  The compiler does not analyze the code in the asm string template in any way, it's just a string on which it performs replacements of %-operands. In

```c
asm ("mov %0, %3" "\n\t"
     "mov %1, %2"
     : "=r" (c), "=r" (d)
     : "r" (a), "r" (b));
```

the lifetime of `a` and `b` ends at the asm, and the lifetime of `c` and `d` begins.  Therefore, it's totally fine for the compiler to use the same register for, say `c` and `a`. This means the output of the 1st move overrides the input of the 2nd move.  This is the classic early-clobber situation, and you'll have to tell this fact to the compiler by means of early-clobber modifier `&`:

```c
asm ("mov %0, %3" "\n\t"
     "mov %1, %2"
     : "=&r" (c), "=r" (d)
     : "r" (a), "r" (b));
```

However, the code that's generated is sub-optimal because it's actually fine if the compiler uses the same register for `c` and `b`, and the same register for `d` and `a`.  This means you don't need any explicit asm code at all, and everything can be described by means of the constraints:

```c
asm (""
     : "=r" (c), "=r" (d)
     : "1" (a), "0" (b));
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Apart from that, your asm code tries to implement `c = b` and `d = a`, **not** `c = a` and `d = b`.