# arm; inline asm; use scratch register;

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

There is some problem w/ inline assembler I could not understand.

I have a function with inline assembler. Inside the ASM block I need to use some scratch register to modify some system value.

```
void setHW(uint32_t val) {
    asm volatile (
        mrc 15, 0, r0, ...
        orr r0, r0, %0 
        mcr 15, 0, r0, ...
        : :"r"(val) :"r0"
    );
}
```

Actually function is inlined by compiler and it's alright, code still works well.

The problem appears when I try to replace hardcoded `r0` with some stub variable so compiler could choose the best possible register to use. It looks like this

```
void setHW(uint32_t val) {
    uint32_t reg;
    asm volatile (
        mrc 15, 0, %[reg], ...
        orr %[reg], %[reg], %0 
        mcr 15, 0, %[reg], ...
        :[reg]"=r"(reg) :"r"(val) :
    );
}
```

Now compiler choose register by itself but actually corrupt the value of `setHW` caller function.
In disassembler it looks like

```
        add r2, r4, r5       ; caller part, r2 contain some intermedia result
        mrc 15, 0, r2, ...   ; inlined setHW(), r2 is choosen as scratch reg
        orr r2, r2, r0 
        mcr 15, 0, r2, ...
        ; caller continue
```

As you could see `r2` is corrupted and everything just fall apart.

How should I define scratch register to avoid this?

Comment: When you added `[reg]`, val stopped being `%0` and became `%1`.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, yep thanks. BTW `[reg]"=r"(reg)` still doesn't work properly. In some cases compiler uses the same register for `val` and `reg` so I get `mrc r3...; orr r3, r3, r3; mcr r3...;`. `[reg]"+r"(reg)` actually fix the problem but now compiler shows error `'reg' is used uninitialized...` and it's necessary to assign a dump value to `reg` and extra instruction appears. Could it be fixed?

Comment: I know you've already solved it, but in the first code block, I believe the issue you're having is that according to the ARM EABI calling convention, the first argument to a function will be in `r0`, so that code is likely clobbering `uint32_t val` with `mrc 15, 0, r0, ...`. Again, back in the ARM EABI, `r4-8,r10,r11` are considered "variable registers", so I think if you had used one of those instead, you'd have been good.

Comment: @rjp ,1) the problem is not w/ the first block. 2) when `r0` is chosen compiler will preserve the value from `r0` before `asm volatile` and restore it after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
void setHW(uint32_t val) {
    uint32_t reg;
    asm volatile (
        mrc 15, 0, %[reg], ...
        orr %[reg], %[reg], %[val] 
        mcr 15, 0, %[reg], ...
        :[reg]"=&r"(reg) :[val] "r"(val) :
    );
}
```

Note the `=&r` to fix the early clobber problem (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html for a description of `&`).

Comment: it's! Thanks David

Comment: Converse "when to use is earlyclobber" question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819794/when-to-use-earlyclobber-constraint-in-extended-gcc-inline-assembly