# C inline assmebly write syscall prints only 4 characters but only when using "=a" as output register

Tags: c, x86, system-calls, inline-assembly

As a uni task I wrote a very simple wrapper for write syscall. It is for i386. Code gets compiled with:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -nostdlib -nostdinc -static -m32 -Wall -g -O2
```

I am wondering why the commented out code prints out only 4 characters, no matter what the num_bytes is.

```
int my_write(int fd, void *buf, unsigned num_bytes){
int ret;
asm volatile (
    "mov $4, %%eax;"
    "mov %1, %%ebx;"
    "mov %2, %%ecx;"
    "mov %3, %%edx;"
    "int $0x80;"
    : "=r"(ret)
    : "r"(fd), "r"(buf), "r"(num_bytes)
    : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx", "memory"
);
/* Does not work
asm volatile (
    "mov $4, %%eax;"
    "mov %1, %%ebx;"
    "mov %2, %%ecx;"
    "mov %3, %%edx;"
    "int $0x80;"
    "mov %%eax, %0;"
    : "=a"(ret)
    : "r"(fd), "r"(buf), "r"(num_bytes)
    : "ebx", "ecx", "edx", "memory"
); 
*/
return ret;
}
```

I am aware i can use:

```
    asm volatile (
    "int $0x80;"
    : "=a"(ret)
    : "a"(4), "b"(fd), "c"(buf), "d"(num_bytes)
    : "memory"
    );
```

and that works just fine as well.
However I'd like to know what is so different between the two approaches above.
It should not matter if I use `=a` or `=r` since the calling convention of i386 states that the return value of syscall is in `eax`.

I tried writing a static buffer and use fixed num_bytes, but the issue remained.
Also i tried compiling with another optimization flag `-Og`. Using any except for `-O2` will cause the code to exit with status 1 immediately after launch, even the version that works ok otherwise. But that could be caused by some other function in the code, as objdumps of the `my_write` section compiled with `-O2` and `-Og` do not show differences. However I did not find a bug in any other function so I`m hoping somebody has an idea.
Thanks for any input.
Edit: excuse the fight with the formatting please

Comment: Your uncommented code looks correct (but inefficient) except for the `"=r"(ret)` output constraint.  The system call leaves its return value in EAX so you need the compiler to pick EAX for that (or you'd need `mov %%eax, %0` after the `int $0x80`, but that's of course terrible).

Comment: Your commented code is missing an early-clobber declaration on `"=&a"(ret)`.  The compiler can pick that register for one of the inputs because it's only a write-only output assumed to be written after all the inputs have been read (like would be the case for a single asm instruction).  But you do `mov $4, %eax` first instead of last, so you overwrite an input; it turns out the compiler put the length there, rather than the FD or pointer, otherwise you'd get `-EBADF` or `-EFAULT`.  [When to use earlyclobber constraint in extended GCC inline assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15819794)

Comment: Don't actually use an early-clobber here, though; put `$mov $4, %eax` last, after all the inputs have been read.  Otherwise the compiler needs to allocate 4 regs instead of 3, and you've clobbered 3 more, leaving only the stack pointer unused!  GCC would need optimization enabled to satisfy those constraints.  https://godbolt.org/z/59ej1cTGe .  Like your current uncommented version, it can only do that with `-fomit-frame-pointer`, which is on by default at `-Og` or higher.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me that you take the *clobber list* of registers as a list of reserved registers, that you want to use for yourself, and think that the compiler will stay away from them.

But that's not the case. What the *clobber list* does is to inform the compiler that these registers may have changed value during the execution of this `asm` and that the values after that are to be considered undefined.

But by using registers by name in your code *and* using a `r` constraint, you risk that the compiler will choose the same register for that constraint that you are using in the code. And that will most likely fail.

For debugging these kinds of issues you should disassemble the generated code and compare it with what you intent. For example, your commented code:

```
asm volatile (
    "mov $4, %%eax;"
    "mov %1, %%ebx;"
    "mov %2, %%ecx;"
    "mov %3, %%edx;"
    "int $0x80;"
    "mov %%eax, %0;"
    : "=a"(ret)
    : "r"(fd), "r"(buf), "r"(num_bytes)
    : "ebx", "ecx", "edx", "memory"
);
```

in my machine disassembles to:

```
mov    0x10(%esp),%eax  // load fd
mov    0x14(%esp),%esi  // load buf
mov    0x18(%esp),%edi  // load num_bytes
mov    $0x4,%eax   // ooops!
mov    %eax,%ebx
mov    %esi,%ecx
mov    %edi,%edx
int    $0x80
mov    %eax,%eax  // store ret
```

As you can see, the chosen register for `%1` is `eax` but you are overwriting it with a `$4` before it can be used.

The non-commented code works just by chance, because the `eax` register is not chosen for anything.

You have two options to solve this. The simplest is to use specific registers for the constraints, as you show at the end of your question. That way there are no clashes.

The other solution is to be extra careful not to overwrite any register while it may still be needed. Something like this:

```
asm volatile (
    "push %1;"
    "push %2;"
    "push %3;"
    "pop %%edx;"
    "pop %%ecx;"
    "pop %%ebx;"
    "mov $4, %%eax;"
    "int $0x80;"
    : "=a"(ret)
    : "r"(fd), "r"(buf), "r"(num_bytes)
    : "ebx", "ecx", "edx", "memory"
);
```

This compiles to:

```
mov    0x10(%esp),%eax
mov    0x14(%esp),%esi
mov    0x18(%esp),%edi
push   %eax
push   %esi
push   %edi
pop    %edx
pop    %ecx
pop    %ebx
mov    $0x4,%eax
int    $0x80
```

That looks a bit silly with all this stack dance but it should work.

BTW, if you write `"=a"(ret)` as an output constraint, then the `mov %%eax, %0` is redundant. That is why your code gets an extra `mov %eax, %eax` at the end.

Comment: GCC will never pick a clobbered register for an `"r"` constraint.  It's even an error to do `asm( "" : "=a"(var) :: "eax")` - it can't satisfy both the constraint list forcing EAX and the clobber list.  The issue here in the OP's commented-out block with `"=a"(ret)` is that it's not an early-clobber `"=&a"(ret)` and EAX is not in the clobber list.

Comment: Also, push/pop vs. mov is orthogonal (because EBX/ECX/EDX are in the clobber list); the key change was putting `mov $4, %%eax;` last, after all the input registers had been read for the last time.  (A worse option would be to use `"=&a"(ret)` which would require the compiler to allocate 4 registers other than EBX/ECX/EDX, so you're right at the limit of how many registers 32-bit x86 has not including the stack pointer.)