# reduce the size of registers pool during compile

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling

I am writing a code for Leon3 processors. I need to reduce the size of registers pool during compile process. In other words, I need to reserve some registers or force compiler to not use these registers. For example, assume that originally I have 8 registers. I am wondering if there is a way to reduce 8 to 4.

ps: I use Bare-C Cross-compiler system (BCC).
Thanks

V.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: i don't use bcc but as you tagged gcc, would this be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682733/gcc-prohibit-use-of-some-registers