# How to disable RBP frame pointer register optimization in GCC when using -O*?

Tags: gcc, optimization, x86-64, stack-frame, register-allocation

When I use `gcc -O2` to optimize my program, gcc changes the value of register RBP. But I want to keep it as FRAME BASE REGISTER, how to do this?

Not the same question as: [GCC: Prohibit use of some registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682733/gcc-prohibit-use-of-some-registers)

Comment: it's impossible to prohibit the use of RSP. And this is not much related to register allocation because RSP and RBP are not general purpose registers

Comment: Unless you really need `%rbp` for some other purpose, this doesn't achieve much. There's less register pressure with x86-64.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'm sorry that I hadn't described my question clearly , As @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc say : "trace the stack frame" is the key words . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`-fomit-frame-pointer`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) is enabled by default at optimization levels -O, -O2, -O3, -Os

You need to use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`

However there are not much reasons to keep the frame pointer unless you're debugging and need to trace the stack frame. In that case, use `-Og` instead

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem use -fno-omit-frame-pointer! :)  I do want to trace the stack frame in real time and save them into logs,but not debugging ,so I think use -fno-omit-frame-pointer is a good way.   :)

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/ has very good explanation with figures.

Comment: It can be useful for `perf` to use efficient frame-pointer stack traces instead of needing `.eh_frame` unwind metadata.

Comment: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=fedora-frame-pointer&num=1 recently tested the performance cost of `-O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer` with GCC12.1 on a Zen3 laptop CPU for multiple open-source programs, as proposed for Fedora 37.  Most of them had performance regressions, a few of them very serious (probably some kind of bad thing happening at a key hotspot, probably didn't have to be that bad but happened to be.)